# webpack-isomorphic-tools loads only blank square instead of image

Tags: webpack, webpack-isomorphic-tools

I have a movies.js file, which has:

```
images: {
        cover: require('assets/images/cover-bigbuckbunny.png')
      },
```

In the component i dynamically use it. Everything works fine. 
But when I make a build with webpack which finally looks like this:

[image: build]

and index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>SCNSmartTV</title>
  <link href="./bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and bundle js has reference to the image, I then open html file in browser with the editor, and the console shows:

[image: console]

the console does not show any errors, and i see that the bundle has reference to this hash, which is in the console, the result is only blank square:

[image: blank]

As i understand, the image is seen, loaded, hashed, referenced... Why is it not displayed?

The webpack config is:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CleanPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var strip = require('strip-loader');

var root = path.resolve(__dirname, '../');

var babelrc = fs.readFileSync('./.babelrc');
var babelrcObject = {};

try {
  babelrcObject = JSON.parse(babelrc);
} catch (err) {
  console.error('==>     ERROR: Error parsing your .babelrc.');
  console.error(err);
}

var babelrcObjectDevelopment = babelrcObject.env && babelrcObject.env.development || {};

var combinedPlugins = babelrcObject.plugins || [];
combinedPlugins = combinedPlugins.concat(babelrcObjectDevelopment.plugins);

var babelLoaderQuery = Object.assign({}, babelrcObjectDevelopment, babelrcObject, {plugins: combinedPlugins});
delete babelLoaderQuery.env;

babelLoaderQuery.plugins = babelLoaderQuery.plugins || [];
var reactTransform = null;
for (var i = 0; i < babelLoaderQuery.plugins.length; ++i) {
  var plugin = babelLoaderQuery.plugins[i];
  if (Array.isArray(plugin) && plugin[0] === 'react-transform') {
    reactTransform = plugin;
  }
}

var WebpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin = require('webpack-isomorphic-tools/plugin');
var webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin = new WebpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin(require('./webpack-isomorphic-tools'));

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    './app/index'
  ],
  resolve: {
    root: [
      path.resolve('./app')
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin( "bundle.css" ),
    webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel?' + JSON.stringify(babelLoaderQuery), 'eslint-loader']},
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
      { test: /\.less$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!less?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap=true&sourceMapContents=true') },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap=true&sourceMapContents=true') },
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
      { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/png" },
      { test: /\.gif$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/gif" },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')},
      { test: webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.regular_expression('images'), loader: 'url-loader?limit=10240' }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please, help, for i tried playing with configs and routes a lot, but still got no success and ran out of ideas.

BTW. Can it work statically? Or maybe it is impossible to launch this in a browser with index.html and ./bundle.js attached? Or do i need any other extra mapfile generated that has to be in the bundle?

Comment: You can try to delete png and gif loaders since files of this types handled by  `webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.regular_expression('images')`

Comment: Thank you so much, Bob Sponge. That's exactly what was wrong about my webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bob Sponge wrote in his comment, I had to

> delete png and gif loaders since files of this types handled by
>   webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.regular_expression('images')

Thank you so much, Bob Sponge and asdfasdfads.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have "data:image" in the src you could try to use 'url-loader?limit=0" so that it wouldn't inline images and refer to the file url instead. Once you've done that report back.

Comment: Dear asdfasdfads, thank you so much. It was a silly thing of mine to use webpack-isomorphic-tools and not to delete this line from loaders: { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/png" }.